# Multidimensional calendar/planning

Tags: time-management, calendar, planning

I'm looking for a software that handles these features, that I can't really find by googling.

- Classic calendar features (days, weeks, week ends , and so on)
- User constraints (vacation days)
- Work constraints (closed on sunday, users can't work more than 6 days/week)
- Fairness system (if someone works an unwanted day, he won't work again that day until everyone has done it, also, same goes for wanted days )
- Preference system ( "I would not like to work that day, if posssible and fair" and " I would  very much like to work that day, if possible and fair")

Ideally, users can complete their constraints and desires  either on the same computer or online, and then the calendar is generated when the admin decides so. (which is then either emailed or available in read-only somehwere).

The app would be a web-app or a proper desktop software, it doesn't really matter as long as it is usable on a PC using Windows 7

Does that kind of software exist or should I create one myself?

Comment: This doesn't sound like something easily handled in a program, beside as central guidelines on using a common calendar service like Google calendar, possibly with some shared documents to keep track of wishes for when to work or not.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid there was no magic software. Îll just have to make it myself !